# PhP - How to place different strings into repeating embedding text?

Tags: php, string

OK so let's say I have a .txt file with the following lines:

Mark
Jane
Ann

How could I make a php code which reads these names line by line and then saves them in a new text file like this:

Hi my name is Mark, what's yours?
Hi my name is Jane, what's yours?
hi my name is Ann, what's yours?

P.S - This is a simplified version of my problem, I actually have a list of URLs that I need to sorround by some XML code and then stack those one on top of another, so it turns out to be one big XML file. The surrounding blocks of XML text are static, they don't change, the only thing that should change is the part where the URL needs to be inserted, of course.

Comment: Have you tried to write some php code yourself? Where did you get into trouble?

Comment: did you try using `explode()` and retrieving the values by array indexing?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Comment: Well, I've tried making a txt file with the static information, and then reading that text file into a php variable, then doing a substring replace with offset, and then exporting that back to the txt file and then renaming the file to xml, and i guess i could do that in some loop for all the domains, but is there any easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file, and then read.

```
$names = file("names.txt");

foreach ($names as $name) {

 printf("Hi My name is %s, What's yours?\n", $name);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this: (result.txt contains your result, and input.txt contains your names)

```
<?php
$filename = "result.txt";
if (!$handleRes = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
}

$handle = @fopen("input.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        fwrite($handleRes, "Hi my name is ".chop($buffer).", what's yours?\n");
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$aString = file_get_contents("text.txt"); // get text from file
$aString = explode("\n", $aString); // split this text with new line character
$aString = array_map('trim',$aString); // remove spacing between left and right
foreach($aString as $index => $strString){  // browse each line
    $aString[$index] = "Hi my name is $strString, what's yours?"; // change to new format
}
$aString = implode("\r\n", $aString); // join array to string
echo $aString;
```